# Spring Boot App in Docker container - SQL Server Integrated Security

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, docker, boot

I have a Spring Boot App (RESTful Service) that runs in a Docker Container and the Database Server is outside of the Docker Cluster, it´s on a special server cluster. In dev, the app works with "Integrated security" without a problem (because of my account), but in a docker container, there is no Kerberos Ticket available to work with.

Is it even possible to add the JDBC Auth lib to the container and use it? I think, from a technical standpoint, I will have to switch to a username/password combo. But maybe somebody has done that already.

Comment: Have you tried to install and configure Kerberos in the Docker container?

Comment: You mean a client for a login to the domain? Not in the container, but on our normal Linux machines. But that´s a good hint, I have to look into it.